# Shared IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T> in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, ienumerable, iqueryable

I've few doubts regarding how shared `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` is accessed in multi-threaded application.

Consider this code snippet.

```
ObservableCollection<SessionFile> files = /* some code */
IEnumerable<Pattern> allFilePatterns= /*some query */

foreach (Pattern pattern in allFilePatterns)
{
   string iclFilePath = Path.Combine(pattern.Location, pattern.Filename);
   SessionFile sfile = new SessionFile(iclFilePath, pattern.AnalysisDate);

   SomeDelegate invoker = new SomeDelegate(sfile.SomeHandler);
   invoker.BeginInvoke(allFilePatterns, null, null);

   files.Add(sfile );
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `BeginInvoke()` passing the *same* instance `allFilePatterns` to each handler called `sfile.SomeHandler`.

Suppose in `SomeHandler`, I iterate *allFilePatterns* in a `foreach` loop, something like this:

```
void SomeHandler(IEnumerable<Pattern> allFilePatterns)
{
    foreach(Pattern pattern in allFilePatterns)
    {
          //some code
    }
}
```

Now my doubt is that: since `BeginInvoke()` is asynchronous, that means all `foreach` in all `SomeHandler` of all the files would execute parallelly (each in its own thread), would the shared instance of `IEnumerable` enumerate as expected/normal? Is this a right approach? Can I share *same* instance of `IEnumerable` in multiple threads, and enumerate it parallelly?

And what if I use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable` in the above code? Any side-effect that I should be aware of?

If its not thread-safe, then what should I use?

Please note that I'm using `IQueryable` for database queries, as I don't want to pull all the data from database. Therefore, I want to avoid `IQueryable.ToList()` as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. Some implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` also implement `IEnumerator<T>`, and return themselves from `GetEnumerator()`. In that case it's obviously not thread-safe...

As for `IQueryable<T>`, it also depends on the implementation. For instance, Entity Framework contexts are not thread-safe, and will only work properly on the thread that created them.

So there is no unique answer to that question... it will probably work for some implementations, and not for others.

Answer (score 1):

I would `ToList()` your enumerable when passing as an argument to the delegate to actually create a new set for the thread to work with and avoid problems.

However, I'm wondering why you would need to have each element of the enumerable enumerated N times (effectively N^2)? That sounds inefficient.

EDIT: Updated with my intent

Comment: That'd still depend on the threadsafety of SessionFile and Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987541.aspx) and friends

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing you *could* do, if working with an IQueryable that is not thread-safe (like an Entity Framework query) is to enumerate the results in one thread, but then pass the results to new threads as necessary.

Then it doesn't matter if the IQueryable/IEnumerable is thread-safe.